# Decode HTML response only the script

Tags: python, unicode, python-requests, httpresponse

I use python to do web scraping, and here's the response I get from HTML:

```
{"d":{"ReturnData":{"script":"\u003cdiv class=\u0027col-12 col-md-4 yd_card borderType\u0027\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t    \u003cdiv class=\u0027inner\u0027\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003ca href=\u0027../UTK02/UTK0201_.aspx?PRODUCT_ID=N1DECHI1\u0027 itemprop=\"url\" title=\u0027《山田卓司x鄭鴻展 微縮人生》限定套票\u0027\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t    \u003cdiv class=\u0027yd_card-thumbnail\u0027\u003e\u003cimg src=\u0027https://imgs.utiki.com.tw/Data/UTIKI_UDN//Images/UTK2401/N1DECHI1_Product.JPG\u0027 onerror=\"this.src=\u0027https://imgs.utiki.com.tw/Data/UTIKI_UDN_RWD//Images/pic_upload-740x420-pic2x(zip).jpg\u0027\" alt=\u0027《山田卓司x鄭鴻展 微 縮人生》限定套票\u0027\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t    \u003cdiv class=\u0027yd_card-body\u0027\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003ch5 class=\u0027yd_card-title ellipsis\u0027\u003e《山田卓司x鄭鴻展 微縮人生》限定套票\u003c/h5\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003c!-- 20180718--\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\u0027yd_card-iconText\u0027\u003e\u003cimg src=\u0027https://imgs.utiki.com.tw/Data/UTIKI_UDN_RWD//Images/icon-date@2x.png\u0027\u003e\r\n                           
                                             \u003cmeta itemprop=\"startDate\" content=\"2021-09-22\"\u003e\r\n                                                   
                     \u003cmeta itemprop=\"endDate\" content=\"2022-01-12\"\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t    \u003cdiv class=\u0027ellipsis\u0027\u003e2021/09/22 ~ 2022/01/12(銷售日期)\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\u0027yd_card-iconText\u0027\u003e\u003cimg src=\u0027https://imgs.utiki.com.tw/Data/UTIKI_UDN_RWD//Images/icon-loc@2x.png\u0027\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\u0027ellipsis\u0027\u003e國立科學工藝博物館 第 四特展廳\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003c!-- 20180718 end--\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\u0027yd_card-price\u0027\u003e\u003cspan itemscope itemtype=\u0027//schema.org/offer\u0027\u003eNT $ 330 ~ 450\u003cmeta itemprop=\u0027price\u0027 content=\u0027330.00\u0027\u003e\u003cmeta itemprop=\u0027priceCurrency\u0027 content=\u0027TWD\u0027\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t    \u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003c/a\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\u0027yd_card-tagWrap\u0027\u003e\u003ca class=\u0027yd_card-tagBtn\u0027 href=\u0027javascript:void(0);\u0027\u003e藝FUN\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t    \u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\u0027col-12 col-md-4 yd_card borderType\u0027\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t    \u003cdiv class=\u0027inner\u0027\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003ca href=\u0027../UTK02/UTK0201_.aspx?PRODUCT_ID=N186Z742\u0027 itemprop=\"url\" title=\u0027會動的文藝復興\u0027\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t    \u003cdiv class=\u0027yd_card-thumbnail\u0027\u003e\u003cimg src=\u0027https://imgs.utiki.com.tw/Data/UTIKI_UDN//Images/UTK2401/N186Z742_Product.JPG\u0027 onerror=\"this.src=\u0027https://imgs.utiki.com.tw/Data/UTIKI_UDN_RWD//Images/pic_upload-740x420-pic2x(zip).jpg\u0027\" alt=\u0027會動的文藝復興\u0027\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t    \u003cdiv class=\u0027yd_card-body\u0027\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003ch5 class=\u0027yd_card-title ellipsis\u0027\u003e會動的文藝復興\u003c/h5\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003c!-- 20180718--\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\u0027yd_card-iconText\u0027\u003e\u003cimg src=\u0027https://imgs.utiki.com.tw/Data/UTIKI_UDN_RWD//Images/icon-date@2x.png\u0027\u003e\r\n              
                                                          \u003cmeta itemprop=\"startDate\" content=\"2021-11-08\"\u003e\r\n                                      
                                  \u003cmeta itemprop=\"endDate\" content=\"2022-01-21\"\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t    \u003cdiv class=\u0027ellipsis\u0027\u003e2021/11/08 ~ 2022/01/21(銷售日期)\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\u0027yd_card-iconText\u0027\u003e\u003cimg src=\u0027https://imgs.utiki.com.tw/Data/UTIKI_UDN_RWD//Images/icon-loc@2x.png\u0027\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\u0027ellipsis\u0027 itemprop=\u0027location\u0027 itemscope itemtype=\u0027//schema.org/Place\u0027\u003e\u003cspan itemprop=\u0027name\u0027\u003e臺北市花博公園 流行館、臺北花博流行館/高雄國立科 學工藝館\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\u0027yd_card-moreBtn\u0027\u003e...more\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\u0027yd_tooltips\u0027 style=\u0027display:none;\u0027\u003e\u003cspan\u003e臺北市花博公園 流行館\u003c/span\u003e\u003cspan\u003e臺北花博流行館/高雄國立科學工藝館\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003c!-- 20180718 end--\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\u0027yd_card-price\u0027\u003e\u003cspan itemscope itemtype=\u0027//schema.org/offer\u0027\u003eNT $ 390\u003cmeta itemprop=\u0027price\u0027 content=\u0027390.00\u0027\u003e\u003cmeta itemprop=\u0027priceCurrency\u0027 content=\u0027TWD\u0027\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t    \u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003c/a\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\u0027yd_card-tagWrap\u0027\u003e\u003ca class=\u0027yd_card-tagBtn\u0027 href=\u0027javascript:void(0);\u0027\u003e藝FUN\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t    \u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\u0027col-12 col-md-4 yd_card borderType\u0027\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t    \u003cdiv class=\u0027inner\u0027\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003ca href=\u0027../UTK02/UTK0201_.aspx?PRODUCT_ID=N1IESPZT\u0027 itemprop=\"url\" title=\u0027Pingu企鵝家族40週年巡迴特展\u0027\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t    \u003cdiv class=\u0027yd_card-thumbnail\u0027\u003e\u003cimg src=\u0027https://imgs.utiki.com.tw/Data/UTIKI_UDN//Images/UTK2401/N1IESPZT_Product.JPG\u0027 onerror=\"this.src=\u0027https://imgs.utiki.com.tw/Data/UTIKI_UDN_RWD//Images/pic_upload-740x420-pic2x(zip).jpg\u0027\" alt=\u0027Pingu企鵝家族40週年巡迴特展\u0027\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t    \u003cdiv class=\u0027yd_card-body\u0027\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003ch5 class=\u0027yd_card-title ellipsis\u0027\u003ePingu企鵝家族40週年巡迴特展\u003c/h5\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003c!-- 20180718--\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\u0027yd_card-iconText\u0027\u003e\u003cimg src=\u0027https://imgs.utiki.com.tw/Data/UTIKI_UDN_RWD//Images/icon-date@2x.png\u0027\u003e\r\n                                                                        \u003cmeta itemprop=\"startDate\" content=\"2021-11-15\"\u003e\r\n                           
                                             \u003cmeta itemprop=\"endDate\" content=\"2022-01-27\"\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t    \u003cdiv class=\u0027ellipsis\u0027\u003e2021/11/15 ~ 2022/01/27(銷售日期)\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\u0027yd_card-iconText\u0027\u003e\u003cimg src=\u0027https://imgs.utiki.com.tw/Data/UTIKI_UDN_RWD//Images/icon-loc@2x.png\u0027\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\u0027ellipsis\u0027\u003e國立臺灣科學教育館 七樓 西側特展區\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003c!-- 20180718 end--\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\u0027yd_card-price\u0027\u003e\u003cspan itemscope itemtype=\u0027//schema.org/offer\u0027\u003eNT $ 230\u003cmeta itemprop=\u0027price\u0027 content=\u0027230.00\u0027\u003e\u003cmeta itemprop=\u0027priceCurrency\u0027 content=\u0027TWD\u0027\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t    \u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003c/a\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\u0027yd_card-tagWrap\u0027\u003e\u003ca class=\u0027yd_card-tagBtn\u0027 href=\u0027javascript:void(0);\u0027\u003e藝FUN\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t    \u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\u0027col-12 col-md-4 yd_card borderType\u0027\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t    \u003cdiv class=\u0027inner\u0027\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003ca href=\u0027../UTK02/UTK0201_.aspx?PRODUCT_ID=N1IESPZY\u0027 itemprop=\"url\" title=\u0027Pingu企鵝家族巡迴特展-商品套票\u0027\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t    \u003cdiv class=\u0027yd_card-thumbnail\u0027\u003e\u003cimg src=\u0027https://imgs.utiki.com.tw/Data/UTIKI_UDN//Images/UTK2401/N1IESPZY_Product.JPG\u0027 onerror=\"this.src=\u0027https://imgs.utiki.com.tw/Data/UTIKI_UDN_RWD//Images/pic_upload-740x420-pic2x(zip).jpg\u0027\" alt=\u0027Pingu企鵝家族巡迴特展-商品套票\u0027\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t    \u003cdiv class=\u0027yd_card-body\u0027\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003ch5 class=\u0027yd_card-title ellipsis\u0027\u003ePingu企鵝家族巡迴特展-商品套票\u003c/h5\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003c!-- 20180718--\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\u0027yd_card-iconText\u0027\u003e\u003cimg src=\u0027https://imgs.utiki.com.tw/Data/UTIKI_UDN_RWD//Images/icon-date@2x.png\u0027\u003e\r\n                                                                        \u003cmeta itemprop=\"startDate\" content=\"2021-11-15\"\u003e\r\n                                                                        \u003cmeta itemprop=\"endDate\" content=\"2022-01-27\"\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t    \u003cdiv class=\u0027ellipsis\u0027\u003e2021/11/15 ~ 2022/01/27(銷售日期)\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\u0027yd_card-iconText\u0027\u003e\u003cimg src=\u0027https://imgs.utiki.com.tw/Data/UTIKI_UDN_RWD//Images/icon-loc@2x.png\u0027\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\u0027ellipsis\u0027\u003e國立臺灣科學教育館 七樓 西側特展區\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003c!-- 20180718 end--\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\u0027yd_card-price\u0027\u003e\u003cspan itemscope itemtype=\u0027//schema.org/offer\u0027\u003eNT $ 280\u003cmeta itemprop=\u0027price\u0027 content=\u0027280.00\u0027\u003e\u003cmeta itemprop=\u0027priceCurrency\u0027 content=\u0027TWD\u0027\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t    \u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003c/a\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\u0027yd_card-tagWrap\u0027\u003e\u003ca class=\u0027yd_card-tagBtn\u0027 href=\u0027javascript:void(0);\u0027\u003e藝FUN\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t    \u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003c/div\u003e","totalCount":"14","pknoList":"N1DECHI1,N186Z742,N1IESPZT,N1IESPZY"}}}
```

After the brackets, I want to extract the script and decode into a normal html format so that I can parse it with Bs4. How can I extract and decode it?

Comment: Please  [edit] your question and share a [mcve]. At least `type(response)` (as currently written, it looks like `<class 'dict'>`)…

Comment: The response isn't properly quoted as pasted in the question, but it looks like a JSON response that would use `response['d']['ReturnData']['script']` to extract the script content.